# The identity det(A) = exp(Tr(ln(A)) for A general

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I understand the proof of the identity in the title for $A$ Hermitian. One uses that any Hermitian matrix can be diagonalized as $A = X \Lambda X^{-1}$, such that
$$
\det{A} = \prod_i \lambda_i,
$$
and we have
$$
\exp(Tr(\log(A)) = \exp(Tr(X\log\Lambda X^ {-1}) = \exp(\sum_i\log(\lambda_i)) = \prod_i \lambda_i.
$$

However, is it possible to show the identity for $A$ not Hermitian? My motivation for this question is that in physics the identity is often used without it being clear that $A$ is Hermitian.

Comment: You do need to assume $A$ is nonsingular, else $\ln(A)$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: this is true for any non-singular A as per
https://doi.org/10.1080/0020739X.2010.500700

Comment: I think you should remove $X$ and $X^{-1}$ and write $\exp(Tr(\log(A)) = \exp(Tr(\log\Lambda)) = \exp(\sum_i\log(\lambda_i)) = \prod_i \lambda_i$ instead, since $\log(A) = \log\Lambda$, since $\log(A) = \log(X\Lambda X^ {-1}) = \log X + \log\Lambda + \log X^ {-1} = \log X + \log\Lambda - \log X = \log\Lambda$.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If $\ln(A) = B$, the identity says

$$ \det(\exp(B)) = \exp(\text{Tr}(B)) $$

which is more usual form for this identity, true for all $n \times n$ matrices $B$ over $\mathbb C$ (avoiding questions about whether $\ln(A)$ is defined, and which of the possible logarithms to use).

One way to do this is to show it first for diagonalizable matrices $B$, then use the fact that diagonalizable matrices are dense and both sides of the equation are continuous functions of $B$.

A second way is to use Jordan canonical form.

A third way is to note that both $\det(\exp(tB))$ and $\exp(t \text{Tr}(B))$ satisfy the differential equation
$y' = \text{Tr}(B) y$ with initial value $y(0) = 1$.

Comment: Wikipedia's page on [Jacobi's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula) treats this identity as a corollary of Jacobi's identity using the third proof method, with the Jacobi identity being used to obtain $\frac{d}{dt}\det(\exp(t B))$.

Comment: You are using that $\exp(\ln A)=A$, which is clear if $A$ is a number (since then $\ln$ is usually defined to be the inverse $\exp$), but in this case it is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an elegant proof with minimal assumptions (only non-singular and square):

\begin{align}
\rm{Det}(e^{B})  &= \displaystyle \lim_{N \to \infty} \rm{Det}\Big(e^{B/N}\Big)^{N} \\ 
&= \displaystyle \lim_{N \to \infty} \rm{Det} \Big(1 + \frac{B}{N}\Big)^{N}  \\ 
&= \displaystyle \lim_{N \to \infty} \Big(1 + \frac{\rm{Tr}B}{N}\Big)^{N} \\ 
&= e^{\rm{Tr}B} 
\end{align}

Now take log on both sides and put $ e^{B} = A$ to get the result.

Comment: How do you get the third equality ?

Comment: Using a variation of Jacobi formula i.e.  det(A + hB) for small h is equal to det (A) + h Tr(adj(A)B) + O(h^2) terms