# Does $Tr \ln M = \ln \det M$ hold for partial traces?

Tags: linear-algebra, quantum-mechanics

I have a $2N \times 2N$ matrix called $M$, and then I am interested in the quantity

$$
Tr_{N} Tr_{2} \ln M
$$
where the two $Tr$ symbols define partial trace. To be more clear on what I mean,
$$Tr _{2} \ln M$$ is a $N\times N$ matrix.
The trace is the sum of the two $N\times N$ blocks on the diagonal, basically.

Now, can I use the identity $Tr \ln M =  \ln \det M$ to write the first equation as 
$$
Tr_{N} \ln \det_2 M
$$
where $\det_2$ means determinant with respect to the  $N\times N$ blocks. Hence, it is like a determinant of a $2\times 2$ matrix, but with block matrices as entries.

I think it is important to specify that these are matrices with **complex entries**.

Comment: With complex entries and $n\geq 2$, your formula in the title is, in general, false!!

Comment: @loupblanc I don't think so. Check https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1487773/the-identity-deta-exptrlna-for-a-general

Comment: Choose the principal $\log$ and consider $M=\exp(\dfrac{2i\pi}{3})I_2$.

Comment: @loupblanc but if I naively write $\ln M$ as $\frac{2\iota\pi}{3} I_2$, then this is satisfied. The trace is $\frac{4\iota\pi}{3}$ and the determinant would be $\exp(\frac{4\iota\pi}{3}) I_2$ which is as required.

Point being you don't have to choose the principal log, Maybe it is important to specify that I define my $\ln$ as $\ln (1-M)$ as $-M-\frac{M^2}{2}-\cdots$

Comment: You are wrong. In your "equality", the LHS is $4i\pi/3$ and the RHS is $-2i\pi/3$.

Comment: @loupblanc So do I have to take the log on the same branch on both LHS and RHS?

Comment: Yes, you have to. If you choose the principal $\log$, then $LHS-RHS\in 2i\pi\mathbb{Z}$ under the condition that $M$ has no $\leq 0$ eigenvalues and $\det(M)\notin (-\infty,0]$.