# Variation of trace of log

Tags: calculus, matrices

I am trying to calculate the variation of the following expression,
$$\mathrm{Tr}~\mathrm{ln}(a+bx^2)$$
with respect to $x$ which is a matrix. Where $a$ and $b$ are constant matrices.

Can anyone please point out what is the general rule for doing this type of differentiation?

Comment: Isn’t the trace of the logarithm of a matrix the logarithm of the determinant? It is for diagonalizable matrices, at least.

Comment: What do you mean by “variation” in this instance? Are the values of $x$ matrices or real/complex numbers?

Comment: @ Thomas Andrews $x$ is a matrix valued function according my text.

Comment: Same question as Thomas Andrews: studying "variation" (think to functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$) is possible when you can say "increase" or "decrease" but you need for that an order on your space of matrices ...

Comment: Do you mean that your matrix $X$ depends on a single parameter, say $t$ such as $\begin{pmatrix}2t&t\\t^2&1/t\end{pmatrix}$ ? Please answer our questions.

Comment: Now, I think that what you mean is **derivation with respect to a matrix** which is a very specific operation. See for example [here](http://cs231n.stanford.edu/vecDerivs.pdf)

Comment: @ Jean Marie, I am sorry for the delayed response (it was not deliberate). Let me post the question in its original form, which may be help to clear point I perhaps missed.

Comment: @JeanMarie The gradient of $\,y=W^Tx\,$ with respect to $W$ is given by the third-order tensor 
$$\frac{\partial y_j}{\partial W_{ik}} = \delta_{jk}x_i$$
But the linked course notes suggest, just after Equation (9), that the gradient is instead 
$$\frac{\partial y_j}{\partial W_{ij}} = x_i$$
Even if one ignores the violation of the Einstein summation convention (the repeated $j$-index), this result is a **vector** which is dimensionally incorrect. The notes are better than average for a _Machine Learning_ course, but they are still terrible.

Comment: @greg Thanks for your thorough comments ; I appreciate your irony about "Machine learning courses"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While waiting for your update that should give some context, let me transform your issue into a simpler one using the insightful comment of Thomas Andrews: the trace of the logarithm of a matrix is the logarithm of its determinant (see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1487773)). Therefore we have the simpler "study of variations" of :

$$\log(\det(A+BX^2))= \log \det(A(I+A^{-1}BX^2)) $$

$$\underbrace{\log \det(A)}_{\text{constant}}+\underbrace{\log \det(I+CX^2)}_{f(X)} \ \text{where} \ C:=A^{-1}B$$

(assuming $\det(A)>0$).

based on an **expansion of $f$ around identity matrix**, with $f(O_{n \times n})=0$, a rather "clean" transformation of the issue.

Now is the turning point. What do you want exactly ?

The "study of variations" being a fuzzy term, it can be understood as I already said in my comments, *individualy* at the level of each entry $X_{ij}$ of matrix $X$, i.e., as a measure of sensitivity (generaly conveyed by differentiation) with respect to a little change of this entry OR *globally* through differentiation with respect to a matrix $X$...

Moreover, your matrices maybe have some pecularities: symmetric, positive definite, etc...

Comment: after going through your answer I guess I understood what I missed. I posted a question on saddle point approximation of integral I am trying to solve. Which is somehow to related to this present question.